# Stop users from entering PHP code in textarea?

Tags: php, html, security, textarea, xss

I have a PHP page with textareas that users can change, and their values get saved and displayed on another PHP page - I'm afraid this could be vulnerable to XSS attacks (or whatever malicious hackers are using today)... I see http://htmlpurifier.org is a nice solution to avoid XSS attacks, and I read in an SO thread that PHP code entered into a textarea is ignored by browsers and not executed server-side.  I just want to know if htmlpurifier will protect my site fully and if there's any chance that old browsers like IE6 aren't smart enough to ignore PHP code like that.  It's my first time making a complex site so I'm tip-toeing around the topic of security... Thanks :)

On a side note, I've used stripslashes and nl2br to avoid formatting issues with apostrophes and line breaks, but is there anything else I should be using to avoid unexpected display issues?

Answer (score 7):

Just use `htmlspecialchars()` on output and the special characters no longer have their literal meaning and won't be processed by the browser.

PHP code itself will be ignored by the browser. The browser will think it is just some large weird `<?php ... '?>` element.

Comment: Technically, `<?` marks a [processing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.6) [instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-pi), not an element. But that's just pointless nit picking pedantry :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out :)  I'm just wondering why the server wouldn't execute what's inside of the user-written `<?php ?>` tags - it's pulling the text from a database record and echoing it into a `<td>`.  I imagined that it would treat the value of the record as text that had been in the PHP file all along, thus executed as usual.  Are you saying this is just improper thinking?

Comment: @tylerl PHP code in a string is not executed. To PHP, a string is just a string of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions specifically...

No, you don't have to worry about the browser executing PHP code that a user has inputted. That's typically only something you have to worry about when you do "includes" inside php scripts, and even then, as long as you structure them properly, you have nothing to worry about. This is because PHP is interpreted server-side (on your webserver) rather than client-side (in the browser). Also, this type of attack would be more in-line with RFI or Code Injection (if you'd like some terms to google), rather than XSS.

Stripslashes can be useful for certain things (potentially with regards to SQL attacks, etc.) but isn't the main defense for XSS attacks.

With HTMLPurifier running by itself, you will be fine against XSS attacks (providing you configure it correctly, etc.)

That said, it's always best to filter user input against a whitelist rather than trying to blacklist 'bad' characters/input. What type of data do you want users to be able to input? Just regular text? BBCode + text? Html?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the long response! I really don't want them entering anything other than a little styling (like bold and italics) and I guess linking would be nice too.  That's about it... I've never tried to set up a text box like this before and I don't want to make it too difficult for them... I'm thinking of setting up this:
http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/widgEditor/
I didn't know I could apply that type of whitelist; could you show me one that only allows bold, italics, and links?  Then I'll configure widgEditor accordingly and do my best to configure HTML Purifier :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is server code. Browsers don't include a PHP interpreter so they won't execute it.

Comment: Well the idea was that it would end up being <?php ?> tags in a PHP document, and you'd think that a server would execute whatever is inside the tags.  For some reason this isn't true?